# Attribute Error when using Turtles in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to build snake from turtles but am running into an attribute error when using the .xcor(), .ycor(), .pos() functions from the turtle class. Basically anything that returns a value from the turtle class is not working in my program. Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time 
import random
screen = Screen()


class Snake(Turtle) : ## create snake class and pass Turtle class into it 

    def __init__(self):
        self.xcors = []
        self.ycors = []
        self.snakesegs = []
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):   
        N = 0
        for segs in range(1,4):
            super().__init__(shape="square")
            self.color("black")
            self.penup()
            self.goto(N,0)
            self.snakesegs.append(super().__init__)
            N -= 20
            xcor = super().__init__.xcor()
            ycor = super().__init__.ycor()
            self.xcors.append(xcor)
            self.ycors.append(ycor)
```

and here is the traceback I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gcinco/Documents/Python/Jett-Black/SNAKE/snake.py", line 49, in <module>
    snape = Snake()
  File "/Users/gcinco/Documents/Python/Jett-Black/SNAKE/snake.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.create_snake()
  File "/Users/gcinco/Documents/Python/Jett-Black/SNAKE/snake.py", line 24, in create_snake
    xcor = super().__init__.xcor()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'xcor'
```

If anyone has any idea what is going on please help, thanks!

Comment: You can't `__init__` multiple times in a subclass. You should really be using composition instead, with `Snake` being a regular class having a list of Segments which are subclasses of Turtle.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling superclass's constructor when calling `super().__init__()`.
if you are trying to to call super's methods, just do

```
xcor = super().xcor()
ycor = super().ycor()
```

Comment: If that solved it, please select it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`super().__init__` is the initialization method of class `Turtle`.  It has no `xcor` or `ycor` attribute.  I *think* what you intend is to call the `x|y cor` *methods* on the segment you created, which is much simpler:

```
segment = super().__init__(shape="square")

self.xcors.append(segment.xcor())
self.ycors.append(segment.ycor())
```

You might have an even easier time with simply:

```
self.segments = [super().__init__(shape="square") for _ in range(4)]
```

Then loop through the segments to set the desired characteristics of each:

```
self.color("black")
for square in self.segments:
   # draw each segment in turn
```